# User based permissions?

Tags: users, permissions

I need to be able to give access to viewing a section of the EE site based on usergroup AND user. For example: I may have a usergroup that I do not want to have access to a blog. BUT, there is a user within that group that I want to give access. So, individual permissions would trump group permissions. Thanks so much for taking the time to help!

Comment: Do you want to control access on just the front-end? Or do you also need to control it in the control panel? Will the students login to the CP to post entries? Or, just via the front-end?

Comment: Just the front end. Need easy interface to administer individual permissions.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this. I've used it, really simple and easy to use on a per entry basis.

http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/entry-access

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, it looks promising. Do you think it is easily adaptable to be per blog, vs per entry? I'd like to have a blog for each child.. and attach certain people that can see that blog, and not have to select people each time my client posts something.

Comment: It should be fine. How are you setting up your blogs? A channel each? Or category? It's pretty powerful, but may need some setting up initially, which is really straight forward.

Comment: I plan on setting up blogs per channel. Can it be set up so that individual permissions trump usergroup permissions? Case scenario: Usergroup A is blocked from viewing channel X. But a user, who is in usergroup A is given permission (on a channel basis) access to view posts in that channel. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Yep, it works just like that. You have two options for either an entry or channel. You set defaults for the channel and can override per entry. The two options ou have are for member groups to view or per member. Ou can set the defaults so certain members or member groups can always view. It also apparently provides this security to the backend, but I haven't tested.

Comment: wow! Thank you! I'm gonna check that out. It's not in the documentation, that I could find. Thank you! I'll post back.

Answer (score 0):

There wouldn't be such type of permission. I think, it would be better to make a member field and update it accordingly if a member can see the blog content or not.

```
{exp:member:custom_profile_data}
    {if member_can_see == 'yes'}
        ### show the content ###
    {if:else}
        ### show the message if member can't see the content
    {/if}
{/exp:member:custom_profile_data}
```

Comment: Situation is too big to edit like that. It's a school, and each kid has a private blog that only certain people can see. So, we would have 300+ blogs with 2 parents, teacher and administrator getting access via user based permissions. I'm willing to pay for a module or even developing a module that does such a thing.

Comment: I suppose I could create a member group for each kid, but that's a lot of member groups!

Comment: Yes, you are right. It seems that you are relating a student to parents and teacher so that they can see the student's private blog. You website already developed so it would be complex. I think, a small plugin/module can be developed for it. Not sure. Can you please share some more details to me or contact me from my blogging site.

Comment: Site is not yet built. We will have a number of blogs and a number of usergroups and permissions. I want individual permissions that trump usergroup permissions. And I need an interface that is intuitive to put individual pernmissions in place. It;'s all about access to blogs, not the CP. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I was thinking the same that the blogs permission will be at front end for individual site member. In previous comment, i mentioned for developing addon for it. This developed custom addon will have its own tag like `{exp:custom_addon:view_blog channel="channel_name" entry_id="{entry_id}"} ######### {/exp:custom_addon:view_blog}` I can develop that addon so that it will have required channel entries tag parameters and all the variable. After checking the member permission for that blog/entry, the member will be able to view the blog or if you would like there can be redirection.

Comment: I'm starting to think that we should just have a membergroup for each child's full name, since there could be up to 5-6 people who have access to that blog. It's kind of easy, uses ee native functionality, and the only downside is that the list of usergroups will be huge... Is there some limit to how ee performs with many usergroups/channels? So, there would be a usergroup for each kid's full name, and any number of teachers, administrators would be put in the group, along with the parents.

Comment: Is there a limit to the amount of usergroups one can have? This client likes to not delete anything. I could see thousands of usergroups in there over time. Any idea how much strain this would have on a password protected community?

Answer (score 0):

In general, one thing to consider is having the same content / views duplicated in 2-3 different templates, with each having different permissions. For example:

```
student_view is a template for students only
admin_view is a template for the admins only
moderator_view is a template for the moderators only
```

Those all might embed some of the same templates that display actual content. But, each main template then could have different, additional restrictions.

So, maybe the built-in EE permissions handle one level of access control. And then you do more fine-grained restrictions with logic in the template.

If you need to restrict members to their blogs on only the front-end:

If you want that all to be in the same channel (or, fewer than 300+ channels), you could map the students' member_ids to category_ids. You'd store the mappings in a special entry, Low Variable, template or directly in the database (depending on how you want to manage these).

Then, for each logged in member_id, you could look-up a corresponding category_id, and then restrict the channel entries shown to only those in the category.

Might that work for what you need?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm confused by the multiple templates... I'm thinking that each student's Full name will be a membergroup, and then I will attach members to that student's name. Then, I can show or not show based on membergroup. It's a lot of membergroups... but, no matter how you slice it, it's a lot.

Comment: Oh, what was the reference to 300+ in your above post? is there a sort of soft spot at which ee degrades? Where did you get that number?  And thanks for the help!

Comment: @dotgarden you had said, in another comment, "So, we would have 300+ blogs with 2 parents, teacher and administrator getting access via user based permissions."